# C++ | spdlog | How to have sincs with different formatters?

Tags: c++, logging, spdlog

I am using `spdlog` library for C++ logging. I have a logger with both `stdout` and `rotating_file_sink_mt` sincs:

```
    auto std_out_sinc = std::make_shared<spdlog::sinks::stdout_sink_mt>();
    auto file_sinc = std::make_shared<spdlog::sinks::rotating_file_sink_mt>("1.log");
    sinks.push_back(std_out_sinc);
    sinks.push_back(file_sync);
    auto combined_logger = std::make_shared<spdlog::logger>("root", begin(sinks), end(sinks));
```

I would like to have different log formats for different sincs. For example, a very simple format (default) for the stdout and a json format for the file-based sinc ( to be parsed by a log indexing service). Is this possible in spdlog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spdlog branch v1.x supports this (not officially released yet but you can give it a try).